# bash file substring add/replace inplace in matches only

Tags: string, bash, awk, in-place, vcf-variant-call-format

I've a [VCF file](http://www.internationalgenome.org/wiki/Analysis/Variant%20Call%20Format/vcf-variant-call-format-version-40/) with different entries and I need to replace (or add if absent) a substring based on multiple matches. e.g.

```sh
head file

### OUTPUT:
1   47746672    .   A   G   .   .   pz_name=GHARTxI16uuT15921;qual=2201;
1   47746672    .   C   G   .   .   pz_name=GHARMALFI17uuM12201;qual=1932;status=RE;
1   47746675    .   C   G   .   .   pz_name=GHARIGANI17uuA10531;qual=1541;
1   47746675    .   C   G   .   .   pz_name=GHARTxI16uuT15921;qual=1440;status=AC;
1   47746675    .   C   G   .   .   pz_name=GHARFSGSI17uuC19091;qual=816;
# ...
```

I need to look at some conditions, in order to isolate only a specific line for each combination of variant-patient (both can be repeated but their conbination is unique) e.g. in order to take 4th line of example:

- that `$2 == "47746675" && $3 == "C" && $4 == "G"`
- and `pz_name=GHARTxI16uuT15921`

in this specific line I then need to:

- add `status=something;` if absent
- replace `status=<something-else>` with `status=something` if present

How can I do it all with some kind of inplace replacement in bash? Is it possible? Alternatives performance effective approaches suggestion will be very appreciated!

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!

Comment: "inplace" editing just means that some command (sed, perl, awk, ruby, whatever) uses a temp file internally. You can just as easily do `command file > tmp && mv tmp file` on your command line and get the same result. So don't get hung up on doing things "inplace", it's a tiny bit of syntactic sugar, not anything to really care about, and certainly has nothing to do with performance. It's not clear what you want to append - status=something but what "something"?

Comment: Where do you get the `"status=..."` from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you're trying do do?

```
$ awk '{print $0 (/pz_name=GHARFSGSI17uuC19091/ && !/status=/ ? "status=something;" : "")}' file
1   47746675    .   C   G   .   .   ad_alt=73;ad_ref=65;denovo=NA;dp_bin=50;father_dp_bin=NA;father_gt=NA;filter=PASS;gene_name_correct=STIL;gq=99;gt=het;mother_dp_bin=NA;mother_gt=NA;perc_alt=0.5252;pz_name=GHARMALFI17uuM11471;qual=2201;
1   47746675    .   C   G   .   .   ad_alt=65;ad_ref=57;denovo=NA;dp_bin=50;father_dp_bin=NA;father_gt=NA;filter=PASS;gene_name_correct=STIL;gq=99;gt=het;mother_dp_bin=NA;mother_gt=NA;perc_alt=0.5242;pz_name=GHARMALFI17uuM12201;qual=1932;status=RE;
1   47746675    .   C   G   .   .   ad_alt=53;ad_ref=38;denovo=NA;dp_bin=50;father_dp_bin=NA;father_gt=NA;filter=PASS;gene_name_correct=STIL;gq=99;gt=het;mother_dp_bin=NA;mother_gt=NA;perc_alt=0.5824;pz_name=GHARIGANI17uuA10531;qual=1541;
1   47746675    .   C   G   .   .   ad_alt=48;ad_ref=49;denovo=NA;dp_bin=50;father_dp_bin=NA;father_gt=NA;filter=PASS;gene_name_correct=STIL;gq=99;gt=het;mother_dp_bin=NA;mother_gt=NA;perc_alt=0.4948;pz_name=GHARTxI16uuT15921;qual=1440;status=AC;
1   47746675    .   C   G   .   .   ad_alt=29;ad_ref=39;denovo=NA;dp_bin=50;father_dp_bin=NA;father_gt=NA;filter=PASS;gene_name_correct=STIL;gq=99;gt=het;mother_dp_bin=NA;mother_gt=NA;perc_alt=0.4265;pz_name=GHARFSGSI17uuC19091;qual=816;status=something;
```

If you want "inplace" editing then with GNU awk use `awk -i inplace '...' file`, or with any awk use `awk '...' file > tmp && mv tmp file`.

UPDATE: given your updated question:

```
$ awk '$2 == "47746675" && $4 == "C" && $5 == "G" && /pz_name=GHARFSGSI17uuC19091/{ sub(/(status=.*)?$/,"status=something;")} 1' file} 1' file
### OUTPUT:
1   47746672    .   A   G   .   .   pz_name=GHARTxI16uuT15921;qual=2201;
1   47746672    .   C   G   .   .   pz_name=GHARMALFI17uuM12201;qual=1932;status=RE;
1   47746675    .   C   G   .   .   pz_name=GHARIGANI17uuA10531;qual=1541;
1   47746675    .   C   G   .   .   pz_name=GHARTxI16uuT15921;qual=1440;status=AC;
1   47746675    .   C   G   .   .   pz_name=GHARFSGSI17uuC19091;qual=816;status=something;
# ...
```

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin A ternary expression is always easier to read when it's within parentheses and in some awks in some contexts an un-parenthesized ternary expression produces syntax errors (I'd have to google for examples). So I always use parens around my ternary expressions.

Comment: Thank you ed, but this will append the `status=something` to all lines matching the `pz_name` pattern and without `status=...`. I need to do it only in lines that matches BOTH `pz_name` and the first 3 condition of the example `if ($2 == "47746675" && $4 == "C" && $5 == "G")`. Moreover, I need to REPLACE (e.g. with `status=something`) if `status=<something-else>` is already present in line. Sorry, I recognize that's a pretty complicate workaround, don't even know if it's possible.... Thank you again anyway

Comment: Is it not obvious how to add those additional conditions? It doesn't sound complicated at all but please clean up your question to make it clear what you're asking and provide a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output where each line isn't over 1,200 characters wide!

Comment: Yes that's much better, I updated my answer. Too bad you didn't include a case where an existing `status=` has to be replaced in your example so we didn't have that to test against. Also too bad the expected output is missing so idk for sure if the output my tool produces is what you wanted or not.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you very much @EdMorton! And thanks to correct me and teaching me how to make more effective questions too!